# Unable to set the PATH variable for jdk

Tags: bash, java-7, bash4

I have installed sun-java in archlinux kde by first building the package and then installing it. This is the way the environment variables are set in my machine:
file: /etc/profile
    # /etc/profile

```
#Set our umask
umask 022

# Set our default path
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH

# Load profiles from /etc/profile.d
if test -d /etc/profile.d/; then
    for profile in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
        test -r "$profile" && . "$profile"
done
unset profile
fi

# Source global bash config
if test "$PS1" && test "$BASH" && test -r /etc/bash.bashrc; then
. /etc/bash.bashrc
fi

# Termcap is outdated, old, and crusty, kill it.
unset TERMCAP

# Man is much better than us at figuring this out
unset MANPATH
```

and file: /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh

```
export J2SDKDIR=/opt/java
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/java/bin:/opt/java/db/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java
export DERBY_HOME=/opt/java/db
```

what I understand from this is, jdk path should be set in the path environment variable but its not. But the attribute $JAVA_HOME is set correctly. Any reasons why am I facing this problem?

Comment: In your PATH= /opt/java should go first other wise java installed in /usr/bin will be taken first.

Comment: @geeky_sh what is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: echo $path
    /home/absolute/.rvm/gems/ruby1.9.3p0/bin:/home/absolute/.rvm/gems/ruby1.9.3p0@global/bin:/home/absolute/.rvm/rubies/ruby1.9.3p0/bin:/home/absolute/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/absolute/.rvm/bin

Comment: @tigran there is no file named java found in /usr/bin

Comment: wait, is it `echo $PATH` OR as you have written above `echo $path`. Variables in Linux/Unix/bash/ksh/etc_shell are case sensitive. make sure you're looking at the right variable. Please add a tag for the OS environment you are using, Linux,Unix,WindowsX. Also, it is better to edit your original question when answering a question about your environment, setup, inputs, expected output, and error messages. So, I'm advising you to edit your question to include output of `echo $PATH`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/profile and /etc/profile.d are processed only for *login shells*, so unless you're doing ssh into the machine where java is installed you won't get those variables.

To have them *locally* (e.g. when you open an xterm on a workstation) put them in the file /etc/bash.bashrc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was a silly mistake on my part. I am using zsh shell. So I was required to put:

```
    export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

in .zshrc file instead of .bashrc.